# Specific setup for each junit test

Tags: java, junit

I have a sequence of tests which have to be fed an input data in the form of a file.However,the exact data content to be fed into each would be specific.
I intend to use temporary files to achieve this.
The Setup method does not take a parameter.
SO ,what could be done so that the setup can be made to read a specific fragment for each specific  test.
The actual set of steps in Setup would be same - creating a  temporary file,but with a specific tailored piece of data.

Comment: Don't use a `Setup` method for this.  Just put what you need directly into the test method.  You might have a private method for the setup, included in your test class.  Then each test method could call that method with a different parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup methods (i.e., methods annotated with `@Before`) are designed for running the same steps before every test case. If this isn't the behavior you need, just don't use them.

At the end of the day, a JUnit test is just Java - you could just have a method that takes a parameter and sets up the test accordingly and call it explicitly with the different arguments you need:

```
public class MyTest {

    private void init(String fileName) {
        // Reads data from the file and sets up the test
    }

    @Test
    public testSomething() {
        init("/path/to/some/file");
        // Perform the test and assert the result
    }

    @Test
    public testSomethingElse() {
        init("/path/to/another/file");
        // Perform the test and assert the result
    }
}
```